# ffmpeg av_seek_frame with AVSEEK_FLAG_ANY causes grey screen

Tags: ffmpeg, media-player, seek

**Problem:**
omxplayer's source code calls the ffmpeg `av_seek_frame()` method using the `AVSEEK_FLAG_BACKWARD` flag. Although not 100% sure, I believe this seeks to the closest i-frame. Instead, I want to seek to exact locations, so I modified the source code such that the `av_seek_frame()` method now uses the `AVSEEK_FLAG_ANY` flag. Now, when the movie loads, I get a grey screen, generally for 1 second, during which I can hear the audio. I have tried this on multiple computers (I am actually synchronizing them, therefore, at the same time too) so it is not a n isolated incident. My guess is that seeking to non i-frames is computationally more expensive, resulting in the initial grey screen.

**Question:** How, using ffmpeg, can I instruct the audio to wait until the video is ready before proceeding.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Actually, [`AVSEEK_FLAG_BACKWARD`](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/avformat_8h.html#ac736f8f4afc930ca1cda0b43638cc678) indicates that you want to find *closest keyframe* having a *smaller timestamp* than the one you are seeking.

By using [`AVSEEK_FLAG_ANY`](http://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/avformat_8h.html#a998c3af80d050fd3d4f6a209fd5a87bc), you get the frame that corresponds *exactly* to the timestamp you asked for. But this frame might not be a keyframe, which means that it cannot be fully decoded. That explains your "grey screen", that appears until the next keyframe is reached.

The solution would therefore be to **seek backward** using `AVSEEK_FLAG_BACKWARD` and, from this keyframe, read the next frames (e.g. using `av_read_frame()`) until you get to the one corresponding to your timestamp. At this point, your frame would be fully decoded, and would not appear as a "grey screen" anymore.

**NOTE:** It appears that, for some reason, `av_seek_frame()` using `AVSEEK_FLAG_BACKWARD` returns the *next* keyframe when the frame that I am seeking is the one directly before this keyframe. Otherwise it returns the previous keyframe (which is what I want). My solution is to change the timestamp I give to `av_seek_frame()` to ensure that it will return the keyframe *before* the frame I am seeking.

Comment: I think your last paragraph has a mistake

Comment: "*might not be a keyframe, which means that it cannot be fully decoded*" What does it mean, only keyframes can be **fully** decoded?

Comment: I am not an expert, but here is how I see it: the video is encoded using "_keyframes_", which are independent images, and "_frames_" that rely on the keyframes. In other words, when you read a keyframe, you can decode the corresponding image. But a frame does not contain all the information you need to decode it, so you need the frames before to be decoded (as opposed to a keyframe). So if you "jump" to a frame without having read from the keyframe before, then you miss information about this frame. Is it clearer?

Comment: I understand what you are saying, however, it was my understanding that keyframes were for quick access. I just assumed that seeking to other frames worked exactly the same, just took longer.

Comment: I think you are wrong here. Some frames require other frames to be decoded. A "_keyframe_" is actually an _I-frame_ (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_compression_picture_types)).

Comment: Thank you. that clears things up. How would you recommend I code this behavior of loading at the exact right time? Should I find some way to seek to the correct frame, or find some way to modify movies and add iframes at desired times (if that is even possible)

Comment: Seek to the first keyframe appearing _before_ the one you desire (or another keyframe not too far from it, as long as it appears _before_ the one you desire). Then, read frames one at a time until you reach the target (that is actually the third paragraph of my answer =)).

Comment: Sorry, I did read it, but I unfortunately have the attention span of a goldfish. I will try this once I am back at the office. CHeers

Answer (score 5):

Completing JonesV answer with some code:

```cpp
void seekFrame(unsigned frameIndex)
{
    // Seek is done on packet dts
    int64_t target_dts_usecs = (int64_t)round(frameIndex
            * (double)m_video_stream->r_frame_rate.den
            / m_video_stream->r_frame_rate.num * AV_TIME_BASE);
    // Remove first dts: when non zero seek should be more accurate
    auto first_dts_usecs = (int64_t)round(m_video_stream->first_dts
        * (double)m_video_stream->time_base.num
        / m_video_stream->time_base.den * AV_TIME_BASE);
    target_dts_usecs += first_dts_usecs;
    int rv = av_seek_frame(
        m_format_ctx, -1, target_dts_usecs, AVSEEK_FLAG_BACKWARD);
    if (rv < 0)
        throw exception("Failed to seek");

    avcodec_flush_buffers(m_codec_ctx);
}
```

Then you can begin decoding checking `AVPacket.dts` against original target dts, computed on `AVStream.time_base`. As soon as you reached the target dts, the next decoded frame should be the desired frame.

Comment: what is the line `auto first_dts_usecs = (int64_t)round(m_video_stream->first_dts * (double)m_video_stream->time_base.num / m_video_stream->time_base.den * AV_TIME_BASE)` for?

Comment: @csguy as far as I remember, first dts could be non zero and in this case it should be accounted for and taken as an offset. I don't know if `av_seek_frame` timestamp should be still considered to be microseconds, but for sure it was in my tests, long time ago. Carefully verify this code against newer versions of ffmpeg for correctness.