# Precise seeking with ffmpeg

Tags: c, audio, ffmpeg

Let's say I have an audio file being decoded with `ffmpeg`. The source format is something like `AAC` where the audio is split into packets. When seeking to a particular time, it is clear that the time will not fall, most of the time, on the packet border but somewhere within the packet duration. Do I have to seek within packet myself or **av_seek_frame** does it all by itself and sets up decoding so that the next decoded frame should start at the position I've requested?

If I use the function **av_seek_frame** with the flag `AVSEEK_FLAG_BACKWARD`, I assume that the next packet returned by **av_read_frame** will be the packet containing the time position I am seeking to. Is that right?

If I decode this packet with **avcodec_decode_audio4**, will the frame returned contain the audio data at the start time of the packet begining or from the time I've passed to **av_seek_frame**? In the latter case how can I find out the frame/packet timestamp so as to estimate the number of samples to skip in the decoded frame? The `PTS` after seek is zero and `DTS` looks useless either.

Is it possible to seek with precision to a particular time using `ffmpeg`?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the source code confirms that **av_seek_frame** does seek up to the packet boundaries.

In order to seek within packets I use AVStream::cur_dts timestamp which is updated by **av_seek_frame** to tell the boundary it has sought to. With that value one can find out the remaining number of samples to skip within the packet. That solves the problem.

Comment: This is correct. I posted some code on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44468529/213871)

Answer (score 4):

There is no frame-exact or audio-sample-exact seeking in ffmpeg, that's an application-level problem. The reason is quite simple: libavformat does the seeking, and it doesn't know what's inside the packets that individual demuxers return. It just has a blob of data with timestamp X and duration Y. It doesn't know anything about that data, you'd have to decode the data to do anything meaningful with it, which is libavcodec, not libvformat.

So, to answer your questions: av_seek_frame seeks to packet boundaries, AVSEEK_FLAG_BACKWARD means the packet will be strictly before the given ts; for audio, that means that the packet will most likely contain your timestamp. However, this is not always the case, because some demuxers seek based on an index, and not each packet may have an index entry. You may have to call av_read_frame() several times before you get to the packet that contains your specified timestamp after the seek.

Other than you calling avcodec_flush(), libavcodec doesn't know anything about seeking, so the output of the next call to avcodec_decode_audio4 will start at the start of the input packet. For sample-specific seeking, applications have to chop off leading samples themselves.

Comment: I partly agree that frame exact seeking is an application-level problem. Since it's possible on a variety of codec/formats, ffmpeg could at least improve the documentation of `av_seek_frame` specifying that seek is performed on `AVPacket` dts. This is confusing since frame index is a presentation related concept.

Comment: seeking is not always performed on dts, it actually depends on the container. If the container timestamps are pts, seeking is in pts; if container timestamps are dts, seeking is in dts.

Comment: Then it should be documented as well. Instead documentation of `av_seek_frame` provides little to no details. How can I determine reliably if container timestamps are on in pts or dts?

Comment: I agree it may be useful to document it. You should submit a patch. :-). As for why we haven't documented it, you have to understand that multimedia literally has trillions of special-case rules or obnoxious behaviours like this, not because we - as ffmpeg developers - want to be irritating, but just because the technology is very non-uniform and requires special cases for all kind of situations to sort-of work. We can make it not work at all or document all special cases, but it would be more confusing. Know your tech stack. :-).